# avoid zooming on mobile browser

Tags: html

I am developing a mobile web-application.I am using jsp,ajax,java classes.I want to stop the page zooming on browser.How it will possible?...I was used meta tag for it but it did n

Comment: I don't think you can. Why would you want to?

Comment: You can match the css to a 'media' IIRC, there you can set up the dimensions. It will normally not allow zoom, if the page is already as wide as it can be.

Comment: it is a application requirement.When the page will zoomed on mobile the images are looking very poor.So i want to stop it.I used one meta tag but it only supports to android mobile.But i want for nokia and even for samsung bada also.

Answer (score 3):

This should work fine for iOS:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
```

On android, it doesn't work for certain devices though such as HTC.

Comment: I used this meta tag but it only supports to android mobile.But i want the meta tag which will support to all mobiles surely.I used <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=0.0, maximum-scale=0.0, user-scalable=no' />.....it only supports to android...please tell me one tag which will support to all mobile...And thankx for your reply it helps me a lot

Comment: It's supported by Palm webOS 1.4.5 (the last 1.x version), too.